# Access form not displaying all data

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a data entry form for a large database. There is a parent form with 6 forms linked with a one-to-one relationship (due to a large number of fields) and several tables linked with a one-to-many. All have auto update/delete checked. The date entry form uses tab control (across 11 tabs) and subforms for some of the tables. I have two problems...

1. If I enter part of the data for a new record in the form (eg fill in tabs 1-3) and then close it, the data appears in the tables, but when I re-open the form the record does not appear, so it is impossible to complete the data entry.
2. When using the tab key to move through the fields in the table, when I get to the end of a tab control, instead of moving to the next tab control for the same record, it moves to a new record on the same tab.

I have searched the internet to try and find a solution to this but I am fairly new to access and not familiar with all the code etc behind it so most of what I've read has been over my head! I would be grateful for any advice!

Comment: Having so many fields for a single record that you had to split them into six different one-to-one tables smells like a bad db design.  I'm not even sure where to start in trying to answer your question.  I think there are about a dozen unasked questions that really need to be addressed before getting into the form design.  Can you give us a better idea of what it is you are actually trying to model with your data?

Comment: +1 to  mwolfe02, I suspect a very bad design there. But beginners have to begin, right ? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

problem 1: you must set the `link child` and `link master` properties of each subform object (the container) in order to allow synchronisation of the subforms.

problem 2: You can use the form's `Cycle` property to define how the tab key behaves when arriving at the last field. Make sure to have your controls properly ordered using the `Tab Order` option in the View menu (Access 2003).

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure the design is not ideal as I am a beginner, but I need at least two one-to-one tables due to the large number of unique fields there are (>255, the database is for a very large household survey). Thanks for the suggestions, I will look into them...

Comment: @user1100175: There are several example database structures for setting up a survey system.  I'd try googling for "normalized survey database structure" for some ideas.  I found a sample access database from Duane Hookom (an Access MVP).  I did not download it myself, but based on Duane's reputation there should be some valuable insights there for you: http://www.rogersaccesslibrary.com/forum/topic3.html.